# How to pass parameter to crystal report viewer with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I want to pass parameter to a crystal report viewer. I added .rpt file to the report viewer, but I can't get the parameter field to bound the variable.

How can I pass parameter to that viewer?

I added crystal report file to the viewer, but in the report file contains 4 parameters. I tried to use CrystalReportViewer1 to get parameter function, but i can't find parameter function.

I also tried to find parameter field from properties there. How can i do it with VB.NET? I want to pass parameter from  main page form to report viewer form.

Comment: CHeCk tHiS tUtOrIaL oN iNtErNeT http://weblogs.asp.net/grblog/archive/2008/08/14/passing-parameter-to-crystal-report.aspx